# How to load multiple templates css and js on handlebars express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a query regarding load of multiple css file and js file on Express-Handlebars. Let's say I have to create the frontend. For that I have a structure like this of HTML Template.

> Template
>
> > Assets
> >
> > > css
> > >
> > > > a.css
> > > >
> > > > b.css
> > > >
> > > > c.css
> > > >
> > > > d.css
> > >
> > > js
> > >
> > > > a.js
> > > >
> > > > b.js
> > > >
> > > > c.js
> > > >
> > > > d.js
>
> index.html

I am using Handlebars on Node.js. My question is I also have to create the Dashboard for that and that template may also have multiple css and js files.

By default Handlebars concept was create one Main.js file where we have a structure and all css and js file linked.

Then we have a different file which will be rendered under main.handlebars file.

If I paste all total css and js then there is a definitely collisions of file and generates many error. According to me This was not a good & efficient concept.

I googled for this issue and found something interesting that on api calls of that page render css. Like this

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    let css = [{css:'/css/style.css'}]
    let scripts = [{script:'/javascript/javascript.js'}];
    res.render('index',{scripts:scripts,style:css})
  });
```

But my question is how I can load multiple css files and js files on that.

If anyone knows this, kindly let me know. Thanks in advance
Any Help or suggestion is really appreciated.